# Yii2: Hiding frontend/web and backend/web from UrlManger

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

I managed to hide `frontend/web` and `backend/web/` using .htaccess file. But the urlManager unable to understand that. I'm trying to create url like `site/index` and it should be something like this: `example.com/site/index` but it creates `example.com/frontend/web/site/index`.

How do I solve this problem with `UrlManager`?

Update: .htaccess in root directory.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
RewriteRule .* backend/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is the one I used in both `frontend/web` and `backend/web`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: please add your *.htacces* rules that you are use

Comment: @Tony done. Would you able to help now?

Comment: it's work for me but when i click about link is like this: "yii2_project/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fabout" i want to show "yii2_project/about"

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](https://github.com/mickgeek/yii2-advanced-one-domain-config/tree/master/advanced) `.htaccess` config and it works fine for me. You need only one `.htaccess` file in your site root directory, and set frontend / backend configuration as described. Maybe this will work for you too.